# Understanding GLib Task and Context

Tags: event-handling, glib

I don't understand the GTask functionality? why do I need this? 
In my mind it is like callback.. you set a callback to a source in some context and this callback is then called when event is happening.

In general, i'm a bit confused about what is a Context and a Task in GLib and why do we need them.
In my understanding there is a main loop (only 1?) that can run several contexts (what is a context?) and each context is related to several sources which in their turn have callbacks that are like handlers.

So can someone please make some sense for me in it all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't understand the GTask functionality? why do I need this? In my mind it is like callback.. you set a callback to a source in some context and this callback is then called when event is happening.

The main functionality GTask exposes is easily and safely running a task in a thread and returning the result back to the main thread.

> In general, i'm a bit confused about what is a Context and a Task in GLib and why do we need them. In my understanding there is a main loop (only 1?) that can run several contexts (what is a context?) and each context is related to several sources which in their turn have callbacks that are like handlers.

For simplicity I think its safe to consider contexts and loops the same thing and there can be multiple of them. So in order to be thread-safe the task must know which context the result is returned to.